# How to do cool visual effects like those in Control (2019)?

Tags: materials, particles, shaders, lighting, effects

I'd like to create visual effects reminiscent of those in Control:

[image: Screenshot 1 Control (game)]

[image: Screenshot 2 Control (game)]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecn9zGd1Qpc&t=38s&ab_channel=YungKudaShorts

I like how the powers in this game distort light in an explosive, organic, and color stretching way, as if using these powers twists and strains the very fabric of reality.

I'm a newbie with Blender, I've just been making models of things and haven't done very much with materials and shading yet. I've tried looking up things like particle effects and glass distortion effects and general tips and tricks, and they've been very helpful to improving my Blender knowledge, but I still feel like I don't see the path to being able to make specifically these kinds of effects.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make these kinds of visual effects? Can anyone point out what kinds of tools or methods I should study up on?

Comment: Try to use post-proccessing for distortion effects. You will find a lot of video about how to use the Compositor. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/index.html

Comment: I was just trying to drive a Refraction BSDF with Layer Weight, but I couldn't get it to look right.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers